# Placing text above \meterfrac numbers in MusiXTeX

Tags: musixtex, music

I'm looking for a solution like `\ccharnote` but for placing text above meter numbers. I read the documentation but didn't find anything.

Comment: It's still LaTeX. Try combining with "traditional" approaches to shift something during typesetting. // Please add a short code-example: Your question is in the process of being closed.

Comment: It would be really helpful to add a compilable document that people can play with and an image of what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
\generalmeter{\zcharnote p{abc}\meterfrac24}%
```

The result in my case is:
[image]

If you need a more specific solution, provide your code and the desired result.